# How to convert circle to ellipse in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Currently I have a round layer which I would like to convert to elliptic layer. Like on the image

[image]

How can I do this? If I select Free Transform and try to pull the circle, it will grow to width as well. I want to have the same width but just to make it longer preserving round shape on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Free Transform** and grab side handles and drag.

[image]

If, as indicated in the comments, you *really* want a "pill" shape which is not really an ellipse, then use the **Rounded Rectangle Tool** and set the corner rounding to 50% of the width o your rectangle. For example, if you want a 100px wide shape, set the rounding to 50px. This will result in a pill shape.

Comment: Very nice animated gif!

Comment: Off topic: How did you create such animated image? What tool did you use?

Comment: @sandalone http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-embed-screen-capture-videos-as-animated-gifs-in-answers

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am using Linux :(. Secondly, about your answer. Your solution will break round edge as it will no longer be circle-round. I basically need to take a circle, cut it to half, then separate new halves and put a rectangular object between halves. This way I will get elliptic body but will also preserve round tops.

Comment: There's a Photoshop for linux? :) .. If you need a rounded-ended rectangle, use the **Round Rectangle Tool** and set the rounding high enough to make the ends round.

Comment: I was talking about anim gif tool on Linux, not photoshop. I can use Round Rect tool if I was creating a new shape, but remember, I have to convert existing round image (raster) to what you called rectangular with round ends. How to do it?

Comment: You'll have to split the shape and draw the sides manually.

Comment: It would aide in receiving answers which helped you directly if you posted *all* the requirements and restrictions in the question.